# APDU response "6985: Conditions of use not satisfied" on data sign

Tags: javascript, certificate, digital-signature, smartcard, apdu

I need to sign some data with a SmartCard and for it I'm using the following APDU commands:

```
// some code with PIN validation, etc...

await sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "002241B60680011284019F");
let signedData = await sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "002A9E9A14" + encodedDataToBeSigned + "00");

// some code here ...
```

This works fine for 20 chars digest value. The problem is that I need to wotk with 28 chars digest value.

For achive that 28 chars condition made some one minor change to the code:

```
// some code with PIN validation, etc...

await sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "002241B60680011284019F");
let signedData = await sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "002A9E9A1C" + encodedDataToBeSigned + "00");

// some code here ...
```

To achieve my goal I've try this change:

from: 002A9E9A**14** + encodedDataToBeSigned (40 chars hash)

to: 002A9E9A**1C** + encodedDataToBeSigned (56 chars hash)

With that changes the APDU response changes from 9000 to 6985

Can any one help with that question?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My best assumption is, that the key in the card is configured in such a way, that the card expects a final hash value and that the length is checked according to its algorithm (apparently SHA-1 with 20 bytes result). You should be able to verify this easily by performing the steps to verify the signature (the one you get from the working example with 20 bytes) and look what hash value you get after the RSA decryption step.

The other possibility is, that the modulus is too small, so for the bigger data input no sufficient amount of padding fits into the input for the exponentiation.

While I admit, that 69 85 is not the most convincing status code for both scenarios, its not too different to exclude the explanations.